# Partial Refund Against a Product

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, refund

It seems only an invoice-level or order-level refunds are possible (for partial refunds).

Is it possible for Magento to process a partial refund against a specific product of an invoice and if so, what would I need to look at extending if I wanted to enable this? Are there any extensions out there that would provide this functionality?